# node not finding project binaries in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

I'm having trouble getting npm or yarn to run scripts that rely on node_modules binaries under Windows 10.

Here's a basic package.json that reproduces the issue for me:

```
     {
      "name": "repro",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^8.0.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "fails": "electron",
        "works": "npx electron"
      }
    }
```

If I run `yarn works` or `npm run works` it opens the default electron app. This shows that npx is able to find the app and that electron was installed successfully in the local node_modules. But if I run the `fails` script under either npm or yarn, I get the error `'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Everything I've read indicates that yarn and npm should add `node_modules/.bin` to the path before running the scripts, and indeed, if I look at the error log generated by npm run start, it contains this line:

```
8 verbose lifecycle repro@1.0.0~fails: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\dusty\Beanstalk\repro\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\dusty\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\dusty\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\dusty\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dusty\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dusty\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Specifically, `C:\Users\dusty\Beanstalk\repro\node_modules\.bin` is in the named path.

I've tried running this under powershell, cmd, and git-bash with the same results both in their native terminals and under Visual Studio Code. I've tried both stable and LTS versions of node. I've tried installing node from the official MSI installer as well as through chocolatey. I even tried adding my `node_modules/.bin` directory to the PATH environment variable.

Running `./node_modules/electron/cli.js -v` pops up an alert box from "Windows Script Host":

```
Script: C:\Users\dusty\Beanstalk\repro\node_modules\electron\cli.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid character
Code: 800A03F6
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

However `node ./node_modules/electron/cli.js -v` works fine and outputs `v8.0.0`, as does ./node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd -v`.  But`./node_modules/.bin/electron -v`gives a "running scripts is disabled on this system" error. I temporarily fixed the latter with`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser.`Unfortunately,`npm run fails`still cannot find the`electron` command after having done so.

I tried running the same package.json under a different user account on the same computer and everything worked flawlessly. This suggests there's something wrong with my environment, but I can't imagine what.

I suspect this is insufficient information, so please let me know what else I can provide. I'm historically a Linux user and not terribly familiar with the Windows ecosystem. This is preventing me from running even the elementary electron guide, and I'm pretty sure it's just a basic configuration issue.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds indeed like there is something borked. Are you able to run the locally installed electron in your project via `./node_modules/electron/cli.js -v`, if yes, is `./node_modules/.bin/electron -v` working as well? I'm asking because sometimes electron does not install correctly. At least on windows erasing node_modules and reinstalling things helps sometimes with strange problems ^^".

Comment: @rhayene I've updated question. The short answer is the former fails with a JScript error and the latter succeeds.

Comment: I would first try a purge: delete electron from your node_modules (or even delete the whole node_modules folder), delete the package-lock.json and then reinstall everything with `npm i` locally. If you have a globally installed electron instance that does not work as well - remove that via `npm rm electron -g` as well. After that, if the problem persists - I would next have a look, whether those files have the executable permission.

Comment: Blowing away node_modules didn't help. I ended up "solving" the issue by resetting windows.